# Error registro php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, registro

en mi codigo php esta fallando lo que es el registro de usuarios. De la nada paso y no se que podrá ser. Les adjunto todos los codigos asi me pegan una mano, por favor. Disculpen las molestias. El codigo esta formulado con PHP, MySQL, PDO. Error de conexion esta descartado. Los campos de la db estan todos chequeados, no es error de escritura, solo que no entiendo porque pasa esto de la nada. Ayudenme por favor. Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Empece una aplicación web con php para creacion automatica de ecommerce y el registro de usuarios es para usuarios no empresas. Nose, si les sirve ese dato. Saludos!

Tambien si me dan un consejo de seguridad para mejorar mi codigo, lo valoro. Gracias!

```
<?php session_start();

$error_registro = '';

if (isset($_POST['validador-registro'])) {

//Validamos si se enviaron los datos correctamente

    if (isset($_POST['nombre_usuario']) && isset($_POST['email_usuario']) && isset($_POST['usuario_usuario']) && isset($_POST['password_usuario'])) {

    //Validamos si el campo ingresado esta vacio o no

        if (empty($_POST['nombre_usuario']) && empty($_POST['email_usuario']) && empty($_POST['usuario_usuario']) && empty($_POST['password_usuario'])) {

            //Colocamos el mensaje de error

                $error_registro = 'Los datos ingresados no pueden estar vacios';

        }else{

        //Limpiamos los datos recibidos

        require_once '../../assets/0/config.php';

            $nombre_usuario_cross = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];

            $nombre_usuario_mysql = $usuarios_mysqli->real_escape_string($nombre_usuario_cross);

            $nombre_usuario_trim = trim($nombre_usuario_mysql);

            $nombre_usuario_htmlent = htmlentities($nombre_usuario_trim);

            $nombre_usuario_nombre = htmlspecialchars($nombre_usuario_htmlent);


            $email_usuario_cross = $_POST['email_usuario'];

            $email_usuario_mysql = $usuarios_mysqli->real_escape_string($email_usuario_cross);

            $email_usuario_trim = trim($email_usuario_mysql);

            $email_usuario_htmlent = htmlentities($email_usuario_trim);

            $email_usuario_imal = htmlspecialchars($email_usuario_htmlent);

            $email_usuario_email = filter_var($email_usuario_imal, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


            $usuario_cross = $_POST['usuario_usuario'];

            $usuario_mysql = $usuarios_mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario_cross);

            $usuario_trim = trim($usuario_mysql);

            $usuario_htmlent = htmlentities($usuario_trim);

            $usuario_usuario = htmlspecialchars($usuario_htmlent);


            $password_cross = $_POST['password_usuario'];

            $password_mysql = $usuarios_mysqli->real_escape_string($password_cross);

            $password_trim = trim($password_mysql);

            $password_htmlent = htmlentities($password_trim);

            $password_password = htmlspecialchars($password_htmlent);

            //Encriptamos las claves de acceso

                $usuario_hash = hash('sha512', $usuario_usuario);

                $password_hash = hash('sha512', $password_password);

            //Creamos el codigo de seguridad que identifica al usuario

                //Numeros aleatorios

                    $aleat_1 = rand(10, 99);

                    $aleat_2 = rand(100, 999);

                    $aleat_3 = rand(1000, 999);

                $cod_seg = $aleat_1 . $aleat_2 . $aleat_3;

                //Validamos el codigo de seguridad

                $codigo_identificacion = trim($cod_seg);

            //Revisamos que no haya registros con el mismo nombre de usuario

                //Registros Usuarios

                    $vld_user_acv = $usuarios_mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM credenciales_usuarios WHERE usuario");

                    $vld_user_acv->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                    $vld_user_acv->execute();

                //Registros Comercios

                    $vld_comercio_acv = $mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM comercios WHERE usuario = :usuario");

                    $vld_comercio_acv->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                    $vld_comercio_acv->execute();


            //Terminamos la validacion de datos 

                $registros_obtenidos_usuarios = $vld_user_acv->fetchColumn();

                $registros_obtenidos_comercios = $vld_comercio_acv->fetchColumn();

                switch ($registros_obtenidos_usuarios) {

                    case 0:

                        switch ($registros_obtenidos_comercios) {

                            case 0:

                                //Empezamos la insercion de datos

                                        $ins_usuario = $usuarios_mbd->prepare("INSERT INTO credenciales_usuarios (

                                            nombre_usuario, 

                                            email_usuario, 

                                            usuario,

                                            password_usuario,

                                            codigo_identificacion

                                        ) VALUES (

                                            :nombre_usuario, 

                                            :email_usuario, 

                                            :usuario,

                                            :password_usuario,

                                            :codigo_identificacion

                                        )");

                                        $ins_usuario->bindParam(':nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario_nombre);

                                        $ins_usuario->bindParam(':email_usuario', $email_usuario_email);

                                        $ins_usuario->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                                        $ins_usuario->bindParam(':password_usuario', $password_hash);

                                        $ins_usuario->bindParam(':codigo_identificacion', $codigo_identificacion);

                                        $ins_usuario->execute();

                                        if ($ins_usuario) {

                                            //Empezamos a crear las sesiones

                                                $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'] = $nombre_usuario_nombre;

                                                $_SESSION['codigo_identificacion'] = $codigo_identificacion;

                                                $_SESSION['confirm_access_user'] = 'true';


                                        }else{

                                            $error_registro = 'Ocurrio un error en el sistema. Intentalo de nuevo más tarde';

                                        }

                            break;

                            case 1:

                                $error_registro = 'El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso. Prueba con otro';

                            break;
                        }

                    break;

                    case 1:

                        $error_registro = 'El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso. Prueba con otro';

                    break;

                }

        }

    }

}?>
```

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Hola, no ningun mensaje de error. Al completar el formulario carga las solicitudes POST ( lo probe con un echo de los datos recibidos) pero no hace nada

Comment: No tengo ningún mensaje de error @Triby